# Trying to sum up a number field in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm tying to sum up a number field  to display a total in my angularjs project.

I'm trying to so something like this:

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in donations">
      {{item.product.cost * (item.product.donation/100)}} //RESULT IS AMOUNT DONATED BASED ON 'donation'
    </div>
```

So the above expression will pull the donated portion of the cost. Then I need to be able to sum up this number to show a total donation.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Compute the sum in your component. A component is not just a template. It's also TypeScript code.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Working Plunker - https://embed.plnkr.co/psoEqO/

The best way is create another `<div>` to display your total.

If I were you, I would create `$scope.donations.total` inside your Controller and display that inside your new `<div>`.

Controller:

```
$scope.donations.total = $scope.donations.reduce(function( prevVal, elem ) {
    return prevVal + (elem.cost * (elem.donation/100)); 
}, 0);
```

Html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in donations">
  {{ item.product.cost * (item.product.donation/100) }}
</div>
<div>{{ donations.total }}</div>
```